# What are the correct headers for this rest request?

Tags: java, php, rest, curl, http-headers

I have a Rest server in java which has this as the post method handler

```
@POST
@Path("{add}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void newTodo(@FormParam("id") Integer id, @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("mark") Integer mark, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
    Student student = new Student(name, mark, id);
    StudentDao.instance.getModel().put(id, student);
    servletResponse.sendRedirect("../create_student.html");
}
```

And I'm sending a request through the following

```
$service_url = "http://localhost:8080/RestWS/rest/Students/add";
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
        "name" => "juan",
        "mark" => "10",
        "id" => "10"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
//print_r (curl_getinfo($curl));
//print_r (curl_errno($curl));
//print_r (curl_error($curl));
curl_close($curl);
print_r($curl_response);
```

I'm getting a `HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type` error response, I'm guessing that it's a problem with the headers, but after trying different stuff and looking it up online I've come to nothing... I've tried passing it with json headers, XML/HTML and changing the mediatype at the server, but I don't seem to be able to get it right, which is the correct set of headers I should use here?

Comment: `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` is the mime-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. make sure curl is sending that (it should, by default, when doing a normal POST).

Comment: It doesn't look like, the curl_getInfo returns this `[content_type] => text/html;charset=utf-8`, so I just need to change the header for the curl call to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then?

Comment: that's the content of the RESPONSE, not what was sent in the request.